# pytorch grad is None after .backward()

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I just installed *torch-1.0.0* on *Python 3.7.2* (macOS), and trying the [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-autograd-tutorial-py), but the following code:

```
import torch
x = torch.ones(2, 2, requires_grad=True)
y = x + 2
z = y * y * 3
out = z.mean()
out.backward()
print(out.grad)
```

prints `None` which is not what's expected.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 17):

This is the expected result.

`.backward` accumulate gradient only in the leaf nodes. `out` is not a leaf node, hence grad is None.

`autograd.backward` also does the same thing

`autograd.grad` can be used to find the gradient of any tensor w.r.t to any tensor. So if you do `autograd.grad (out, out)` you get `(tensor(1.),)` as output which is as expected.

Ref:

- Tensor.backward (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.Tensor.backward)
- autograd.backward (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.backward)
- autograd.grad (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.grad)

Comment: Is the documentation at [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html#gradients) wrong?

Comment: No! Note that they do `x.grad` which prints `dout/dx`. You are printing `out.grad`

Comment: Fantastic post. Thanks. So let's say we need to do this several times, so we autograd.grad(out,in,retain_graph=True). Do we need to zero the gradient here???? Or is it that each time we call our autograd.grad it is re-computing the gradient from zero anyways, so we don't need to as in optimizer.zero_grad()???

Comment: I don't think you need to call `zero_grad` when you use `autograd.grad`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the non-leaf gradients you can use `register_hook` on your non-leaf tensors in order to save them somewhere (as shown in the following answer: [How to return intermideate gradients (for non-leaf nodes) in pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55305262/how-to-return-intermideate-gradients-for-non-leaf-nodes-in-pytorch) ) .