# How to return intermideate gradients (for non-leaf nodes) in pytorch?

Tags: python, gradient, pytorch

My question is concerning the syntax of pytorch `register_hook`.

```
x = torch.tensor([1.], requires_grad=True)
y = x**2
z = 2*y

x.register_hook(print)
y.register_hook(print)

z.backward()
```

outputs:

```
tensor([2.])
tensor([4.])
```

this snippet simply prints the gradient of `z` w.r.t `x` and `y`, respectively.

Now my (most likely trivial) question is how to return the intermediate gradients (rather than only printing)?

UPDATE:

It appears that calling `retain_grad()` solves the issue for leaf nodes. ex. `y.retain_grad()`.

However, `retain_grad` does not seem to solve it for non-leaf nodes. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "solves the issue for leaf nodes"? `y` is a non-leaf node (since its value was produced from a differentiable function of another tensor, which makes it a non-leaf node in the [computational graph](https://pytorch.org/blog/computational-graphs-constructed-in-pytorch/)). Can you give an example of a case in which `retain_grad` does not solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use those hooks to store the gradients in a global variable:

```
grads = []
x = torch.tensor([1.], requires_grad=True)
y = x**2 + 1
z = 2*y

x.register_hook(lambda d:grads.append(d))
y.register_hook(lambda d:grads.append(d))

z.backward()
```

But you most likely also need to remember the corresponding tensor these gradients were computed for. In that case, we slightly extend above using a `dict` instead of `list`:

```
grads = {}
x = torch.tensor([1.,2.], requires_grad=True)
y = x**2 + 1
z = 2*y

def store(grad,parent):
    print(grad,parent)
    grads[parent] = grad.clone()

x.register_hook(lambda grad:store(grad,x))
y.register_hook(lambda grad:store(grad,y))

z.sum().backward()
```

Now you can, for example, access tensor `y`'s grad simply using `grads[y]`