# Convert each element of pandas dataframe into dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to add feature index to each element of pandas dataframe such that each element will be like `column_number:feature_value`. For example, if input is like this:

```
        col1    col2
row1    1.23    2.24
row2    0.42    5.52
```

Then, the output dataframe should be like this:

```
        col1    col2
row1    1:1.23    2:2.24
row2    1:0.42    2:5.52
```

Here the key and value of the dict of each element is `int` and `float` type respectively. Here is my code:

```
f1 = pd.DataFrame()
# removing the ground truth
X = feature_matrix1.drop(['Disease'], axis=1)
X1 = X.copy()
for i in tqdm(range(X.shape[0])):
    for j in range(X.shape[1]):
        X1.iloc[i,j] = {}
        X1.iloc[i,j][i] = X1.iloc[i,j]
```

The size of X is 1235x13160. But I am getting an error of `Incompatible indexer with Series`. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to get my desired output format:

```
f_out = open('check_features.csv','w')
X = feature_matrix1.drop(['Disease'], axis=1)
Y = feature_matrix1['Disease'].tolist()
for i in tqdm(range(X.shape[0])):
    line = ''
    line += str(Y[i]) + '\t'
    for j in range(X.shape[1]):
        line +=  str(j+1) + ':' + str(X.iloc[i,j]) + '\t'
    line += '\n'
    f_out.write(line)

f_out.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert to string and use `radd` to get expect output:

```
>>> df.astype(str).radd([f'{i+1}:' for i in range(len(df.columns))])

        col1    col2
row1  1:1.23  2:2.24
row2  1:0.42  2:5.52
```

Comment: Yes. I was expecting the same. Thanks for short command. My way is traditional type (as I am not a good programmer ;) ). Thanks to you for your answer and to others too.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if one fits your need. It's important for other user with a similar case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`df.columns.get_loc()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) to get the column integer location number (0-based) and then string concatenate with the column values for each column, as follows:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = str(df.columns.get_loc(col) + 1) + ':' + df[col].astype(str)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

        col1    col2
row1  1:1.23  2:2.24
row2  1:0.42  2:5.52
```

Answer (score 0):

It works

```
for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda x:f"{c[-1]}:{x}")
```

result

```
        col1    col2
row1  1:1.23  2:2.24
row2  1:0.42  2:5.52
```

Answer (score 0):

Short version
In

```
[f"{i+1}:" for i in range(df.shape[1])] + df.astype(str)
```

Out

```
        col1    col2
row1  1:1.23  2:2.24
row2  1:0.42  2:5.52
```